# Visual Studio Code edit file

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I try to edit a file in visual studio code, I type the command 'code filename.ps1' and the code used to automatically open as a second tab in the editor.

Now, when I do the same thing, it opens in a new window.   I have not changed anything in my settings and I can't find an associated Preference that controls this.

Anyone know exactly the default setting that I need to look at?

Comment: Maybe:  "window.openFilesInNewWindow": "off",

Comment: Checked that, it is currently set to 'off'.

Answer (score 0):

According to [CLI Options](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_core-cli-options) this should work:

```
code -r filename.ps1
```

>

```
-r or --reuse-window
```

> Forces opening a file or folder in the last active window.

Comment: I factory defaulted my Visual Studio Code install and now 'code filename' defaults to opening a new tab as opposed to opening a new instance of VSC.  Not sure what caused that change.